# How to remove duplicate from list of tuple when order is important

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

I have seen some similar answers, but I can't find something specific for this case.

I have a list of tuples:

`[(5, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)]`

What I want is to remove tuples from this list only when first element of tuple has occurred previously in the list and the tuple which remains should have the smallest second element.

So the output should look like this:

`[(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a linear time approach that requires two iterations over your original list.

```
t = [(5, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)] # test case 1
#t = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)] # test case 2
smallest = {}
inf = float('inf')

for first, second in t:
    if smallest.get(first, inf) > second:
        smallest[first] = second

result = []
seen = set()

for first, second in t:
    if first not in seen and second == smallest[first]:
        seen.add(first)
        result.append((first, second))

print(result) # [(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)] for test case 1
              # [(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)] for test case 2
```

Comment: This fails in `t = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)]`

Comment: @AdamSmith how so? Should the result not be `[(5, 3), (3, 1), (6, 4)]`?

Comment: per the question: "the tuple which remains should have the smallest second element" so it should still be `[(5, 0), ...]`

Comment: @AdamSmith I completely overlooked that part of the specification.

Comment: @AdamSmith adjusted!

Comment: You may be able to save time by reversing your test order (`if first not in seen and second == smallest[first]`) but that's the micro-est of optimizations. Looks great!

Comment: @AdamSmith good catch. By the way, I assumed that in the second test case the original order should be kept, i.e. the first entry is `(3, 1)` and `(5, 0)` does not slide to the front.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compact version I came up with using OrderedDict and skipping replacement if new value is larger than old.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)]
d = OrderedDict()

for item in a:

    # Get old value in dictionary if exist
    old = d.get(item[0])

    # Skip if new item is larger than old
    if old:
        if item[1] > old[1]:
            continue
        #else:
        #    del d[item[0]]

    # Assign
    d[item[0]] = item

list(d.values())
```

Returns:

```
[(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)]
```

Or if you use the else-statement (commented out):

```
[(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)]
```

Comment: Wrong result, per the question.

Comment: New solution should work, but I'm worried about how "insertion order" is defined for OrderedDicts. Does `d[first] = item` count as insertion if `first in d`? If not, you may be getting out-of-order results.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yep I was also interested. My tests indicate this work.

Comment: @AdamSmith "Does d[first] = item count as insertion if first in d" <- No! That means (key, value) pairs don't get pushed to the end if the key is already in the OrderedDict.

Comment: @AdamSmith Which means for `a = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)]` this answer gives the result `[(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)]` while my answer gives the result `[(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)]`. I think OP did not properly specifiy which of these two results would be the expected one - so I think both answers are fine.

Comment: @AntonvBR I'm not so sure. "Keeping order", at least to me, means that a tuple cannot suddenly slide to the front of the result list only because it shares the first element with a tuple from the front. Regarding "if old" - my comment was bogus and I deleted it.

Comment: @timgeb Ok, I accept you got a valid point :). I added an else-statement if the desired output is [(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you need to know two things:

1. The tuple that has the smallest second element for each first element.
2. The order to index each first element in the new list

We can get #1 by using `itertools.groupby` and a `min` function.

```
import itertools
import operator

lst = [(3, 1), (5, 3), (5, 0), (3, 2), (6, 4)]
# I changed this slightly to make it harder to accidentally succeed.
# correct final order should be [(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)]

tmplst = sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
groups = itertools.groupby(tmplst, operator.itemgetter(0))
# group by first element, in this case this looks like:
# [(3, [(3, 1), (3, 2)]), (5, [(5, 3), (5, 0)]), (6, [(6, 4)])]
# note that groupby only works on sorted lists, so we need to sort this first

min_tuples = {min(v, key=operator.itemgetter(1)) for _, v in groups}
# give the best possible result for each first tuple. In this case:
# {(3, 1), (5, 0), (6, 4)}
# (note that this is a set comprehension for faster lookups later.
```

Now that we know what our result set looks like, we can re-tackle `lst` to get them in the right order.

```
seen = set()
result = []
for el in lst:
    if el not in min_tuples:  # don't add to result
        continue
    elif el not in seen:      # add to result and mark as seen
        result.append(el)
        seen.add(el)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a particularly efficient solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
# I switched (5, 3) and (5, 0) to demonstrate sorting capabilities.
list_a = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)]

# Create a list to contain the results
list_b = []

# Create a list to check for duplicates
l = []

# Sort list_a by the second element of each tuple to ensure the smallest numbers
list_a.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])

# Iterate through every tuple in list_a
for i in list_a:

    # Check if the 0th element of the tuple is in the duplicates list; if not:
    if i[0] not in l:

        # Add the tuple the loop is currently on to the results; and
        list_b.append(i)

        # Add the 0th element of the tuple to the duplicates list
        l.append(i[0])

>>> print(list_b)
[(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)]
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This fails if the correct order doesn't correspond with the second element order (i.e. `[(3,1), (5, 3), ...]`

Answer (score 0):

## Using `enumerate()` and list comprehension:

```
def remove_if_first_index(l):
    return [item for index, item in enumerate(l) if item[0] not in [value[0] for value in l[0:index]]]
```

## Using `enumerate()` and a for loop:

```
def remove_if_first_index(l):

    # The list to store the return value
    ret = []

    # Get the each index and item from the list passed
    for index, item in enumerate(l):

        # Get the first number in each tuple up to the index we're currently at
        previous_values = [value[0] for value in l[0:index]]

        # If the item's first number is not in the list of previously encountered first numbers
        if item[0] not in previous_values:
            # Append it to the return list
            ret.append(item)

    return ret
```

## Testing

```
some_list = [(5, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)]
print(remove_if_first_index(some_list))
# [(5, 0), (3, 1), (6, 4)]
```

Comment: this is slower for large lists than building a set of `seen` and checking membership, and also suffers from the same issues as the other answers in that it does not properly choose which element gets to stay. This code fails for `some_list = [(5, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (6, 4)]`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this idea without seeing the @Anton vBR's answer.

```
import collections

inp = [(5, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)]

od = collections.OrderedDict()
for i1, i2 in inp:
    if i2 <= od.get(i1, i2):
        od.pop(i1, None)
        od[i1] = i2
outp = list(od.items())
print(outp)
```